# Flowchart to determine whether the given input number is an integer or a floating point?

Tags: floating-point, integer, pseudocode, flowchart

Can a general flowchart be drawn (without using any specific programming language) to determine whether the given input number is an integer or a floating point?

Comment: If input was `"340282366920938463463374607431768211456"` (2^128), that is something that is exactly savable as a floating point yet exceeds the range on most integer types.  Should input like this get classified as a floating point or an integer?  If input was `1.0e100000000`, should that get classified as a floating point even though it exceeds the floating point finite range?  Should `"0.1"` get classified as a floating point even though its _exact_ value is not encodable as a floating point (which usually uses powers-of-2)?

Comment: In what form do you get the input number? What operations/functions does your pseudocode allow? Also, in most programming languages "floating-point" is something like the type of a variable (or constant/parameter/...), e.g. `1.0` could be a floating-point number, even though it (mathematically) represents the same value as the integer `1`.